# cierre de sesión no funciona vb.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

Tengo un problema con mi pagina, cuando cierro sesión destruyo las variables de sesión, si regreso a la pagina anterior con la flecha del navegador muestra mi pagina "menú" que ya tiene la validación de que no entre si las variables de sesión están vacías (ese el problema que tengo), he verificado que cuando actualizo mi pagina "menú" inmediatamente realiza lo que quiero que vaya a la pagina de logueo, estoy trabajando con web pages de diseño y contenido (similar a master pages) en vb.net

```
If Not Page.ispostback  Then
    If Session("nombre") Is Nothing And Session("numero") Is Nothing Then
        Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx")
    Else
        PageData("Title") = "Escriba el título aquí"
        Layout = "_Layout.vbhtml"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Creo que a la pregunta le hace falta un poco de información para poder entender mejor cual es el error en si. Podrias @Drago25 podrias detallar un poco más el problema?. Saludos.

Comment: Faltaría saber un poco mas de tu proceso de cierre de sesión pero tiene toda la pinta de ser un problema con el caché del navegador

Comment: desde algún otro lado estas volviendo a definir las variables.

Comment: y como terminaría todas las variables de sesión si es el caso de que las estuviera volviendo a definir, y si fuera el cache que tendría que hacer

Comment: antes que hagas el  Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx") considerar la respuesta de @Elenasys http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/4354/822 que elimines Session.Remove("nombre") y Session.remove("numero")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que el problema es que no estas eliminando correctamente las variables de sesión.

Asegura para eliminar las variables:

```
Session.Remove("nombre")
Session.Remove("numero")
```

Para eliminar todas:

```
Session.Clear();
```

Despúes de realizar esto podrás encontrar que las variables son eliminadas correctamente:

```
If (Session("nombre") Is Nothing And Session("numero") Is Nothing) Then
    Response.Redirect("~/Index.aspx")
...
...
...
```

Asegura que la clase usada es `HttpContext.Current.Session`.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que aconsejaría es que no uses el objeto Session para implementar seguridad en tu sitio web, debes usar la seguridad de asp.net

aqui

[Login – Usando Password con Hash](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com/2010/05/login-usando-password-con-hash.html)

explico como podrias hacerlo

Como primer paso defiens en el `web.config`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="appNameAuth" path="/" loginUrl="frmLogin.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" protection="All" />
 </authentication>

 <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
 </authorization>
```

Te autenticas usando

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUser.Text, chkPersistLogin.Checked);
```

Para realizar un logoff usarias

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
```

asi de simple esto redirecciona al login y no dejara que ingreses a otra pagina sino esta autenticado

Usar `Session` para la seguridad es una pesima idea

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que está ocurriendo es que el navegador está guardando en cache tu página de menú. Esto haría que, al cerrar sesión y volver a la página anterior, el navegador no realice una petición a servidor y esté mostrando la versión que tiene cacheada.

Esto lo podrías comprobar abriendo las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador y comprobando en las peticiones de red los encabezados de la respuesta que indican al navegador si la página es cacheable y como

[image: Revisar caché]

Si observas la imagen correspondiente a una petición a S.O. verán como los encabezados están indicando que no se cachee

Para hacer que tu página no se cachee deben se añadir este código a tu página (por ejemplo en el `Page_Init`) *(código obtenido de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/918346/1724791) de S.O en inglés)*

```
'Stop Caching in IE
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(System.Web.HttpCacheability.NoCache)

'Stop Caching in Firefox
Response.Cache.SetNoStore()
```

Por cierto, coincido con [Leandro Tuttini](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/2600) en que no deberías usar las variables de sesión y menos para implementar la seguridad.